# How do I genuinely calculate level progress with an algorithm?

Tags: php, math

in my app I get a var `$curxp` which holds an int, now I want to create a function that automatically returns `$xplvlup` (which holds an int how much total XP is needed for the next level and a function that returns the current level.

Now I could simply hardcode with switch statements and calculated numbers like:

```
switch($curxp){
    case <10: $xplvlup = 10; break;
}
```

But it would be much nicer if I could use an algorithm so there is no max level.
I know I have to work with exponents to get a nice curve, but I just dont know how to start things up.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Oltarus I came to the following solution:

```
$curxp = 20;

function level($lvl){
    return $xp = pow($lvl,2) + 5 * $lvl;
}

$lvl = 0;
while (level($lvl) < $curxp) $lvl++;
$totxp = level($lvl);
$xplvlup = level($lvl) - $curxp;

echo 'Level: '.$lvl."<br />";
echo 'Total XP: '.$totxp."<br />";
echo 'XP needed for Levelup: '.$xplvlup;
```

Comment: Do you have a formula for calculating the xp requirements per level?

Comment: Hey, you can change `return $xp = pow($lvl,2) + 5 * $lvl;` to `return pow($lvl,2) + 5 * $lvl;`. There is no need to define $xp within return, because the function will always stop after so it will never be used.

Comment: in the final implementation of course I reduced the code and actually I wrote a helper for cakephp, but thanks for the input Kokos, glad you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you calculate the levels, but let's say you have a function `level($n)` that returns how many XP are needed to have level `$n`.

```
$n = 0;
while (level($n) < $curxp) $n++;
$xplvlup = level($n) - $curxp;
```

Answer (score 3):

If for instance you would have the first level-up require 500 xp, and then every level you will need 10% more xp you could do something like this:

```
function xp_needed($cur_lvl){

    $start = 500;
    return   $start*pow(1.1,($cur_lvl-1));

}
```

For every level, the xp is calculated by `500 * 1.1^(level-1)`

**Edit**

Woops, `$cur_lvl` should be substracted by 1.